# Is there a way to constantly stream Google Data Studios onto a Chromecast. Looking to create a data monitor for the office

Tags: chromecast, looker-studio

Is there a way to stream it so it constantly plays in the background? I currently have screenshots used in Ambient mode, but would love to have reports that update themselves and on the chrome cast.

Answer (score 0):

yes - https://support.google.com/chromecast/answer/3228332?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en

not sure if it's totally what you're looking for but you can add a community visualization that cycles through all your data on a loop. In the top bar click the community visualizations icon, then explore more, and select AutoPlay.

[image]

Here are the instructions to set-up along with a demo - https://datastudio.google.com/u/0/reporting/859cc3f8-8968-43d0-9e2e-f47300b66a31/page/GUgQB